# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' [start point : from keras.layers.core import Activation]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Estimate parameters with lstm.py", line 13, in <module>
         from keras.layers.core import Activation
    File "/home/zeus/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
         from keras import models
    File "/home/zeus/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 19, in <module>
         from keras import backend
   File "/home/zeus/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 36, in <module>
         from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config
   ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'
```

I have tried `from tensorflow import keras` instead of `import keras`, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many causes that this happens.

**Solution 1**: upgrade tensorflow

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

**Solution 2**: Change import Methods

Instead of this

```
import keras
```

Use this one

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

**if you are using image**, then instated of this

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

use this one

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `TensorFlow` and `keras` version mismatch error.

Importing `keras` from `TensorFlow` or upgrading `TensorFlow` will solve this issue.(@paraphrased by Ali Aref)

OR

Make sure you are using same versions of `TensorFlow` and `keras` or atleast latest `TensorFlow version 2.7` to execute your code which may fix this issue.

Check `TensorFlow` and `keras` version using below code:

```
import tensorflow
print(tf.__version__)
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

And try installing the same `keras` version as existing installed `TensorFlow`:

```
!pip install keras==<enter installed tensorflow version>
```

Run your code again and let us know if issue still persists.